# Modify open cart controller without losing it after an upgrade?

Tags: php, opencart, upgrade

I'm new to opencart and I had to modify a controller in order to show a list of featured products on the site's header.

The change was very easy, however I think I have to worry about losing the controller's modification if I update open cart.

My question is, what's the best approach to do this kind of modifications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is very common and is usually solved by [VQMod](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart).

VQMod is a PHP script that makes changes "on the fly" by reading XML files. So you describe the changes you want to make using basic "search&replace" functionality into an XML file, without having to edit the original file.